# Forbidding SVN commit lacking description

Tags: svn, version-control, input-filtering

I have an SVN repository and I need the commits to fail if no description is entered. Is this possible to do, preferably server-side? (The users use several different tools for interacting with the repository; although if this were possible client-side in TortoiseSVN, that would alleviate the problem)

Google has not been very helpful, can you give me some pointers?

Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yup, you'll want to write a pre-commit hook in the repository which fails with an appropriate error message to send back to the client.

If you look in the "hooks" directory of a freshly created repository, you'll find a `pre-commit.tmpl` file. That contains instructions, and the sample even checks that the log message contains text - just what you want.

So, you should be able to rename `pre-commit.tmpl` to `pre-commit` and make it executable, then give it a whirl. I suggest you try it on a sandbox repository before a production one though, to avoid angry users being unable to commit while you get it right :)

Answer (score 0):

You can do that using [repository hooks](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.5/svn.reposadmin.create.html#svn.reposadmin.create.hooks). In your case, you want a pre-commit hook that will check the message and reject the commit if it is empty.

Answer (score 0):

The [FreeBSD](http://www.freebsd.org/) project has some examples you may want to use.  See the public [svn repo](http://svn.freebsd.org/viewvc/base/svnadmin/hooks/) with hooks.